# r and ggplot not shading US or UK

Tags: r, ggplot2

my first post here and I'm a complete R noob.

I am trying to make a world map that shades each country as it pertains to the frequency of their data.

[image: map]

Here is the code that I'm working with:

```
WorldData <- map_data('world')
WorldData %>% filter(region != "Antarctica") -> WorldData
WorldData <- fortify(WorldData)
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_map(data=WorldData, map=WorldData,
                  aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, map_id=region),
                  fill="white", colour="#7f7f7f", size=0.5)
p <- p + geom_map(data=Total, map=WorldData,
                  aes(fill=Total$freq, map_id=region),
                  colour="#7f7f7f", size=0.5)
p <- p + coord_map("rectangular", lat0=0, xlim=c(-180,180), ylim=c(-60, 90))
p <- p + scale_fill_continuous(low="thistle2", high="darkred", 
                               guide="colorbar")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c())
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c())
p <- p + labs(fill="legend", title="Who downloads the most?", x="", y="")
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
p
```

Some of this code was even found here. The problem I'm having is that I cannot shade the US or UK. I have checked the title of the regions in the mapdata('World') and they are both shown as USA and UK and not fully spelled out names, which I have applied changed my dataframe to reflect.

Also secondly, if anyone could point me towards the right things to google/search/find how to make this same type of map but with dots of different sizes around clusters of long/lat coords show it might show larger dots near cities etc.

Thanks.

Comment: As always (see the [help] pages on how to and how not-to ask questions) ... SO expects a dataset to work with if you expect code (or even identification of errors from code). Use [edit] facilities to improve the question. Two part questions are also strongly discouraged, so I would suggest first searching and then if you come up empty on the second part posting another question (with data).

Comment: `grep("US|UK", unique(WorldData$region), value=TRUE)`